# Download HTML Form Data into Excel in INTERNET EXPLORER

Tags: javascript, html, excel, forms, internet-explorer

I am trying to Download HTML Form data into excel on Clicking Submit button. It is Happening in Chrome, but not in Explorer. Following is the code. It is working fine in CHROME. Plz help
I am trying to Download HTML Form data into excel on Clicking Submit button. It is Happening in Chrome, but not in Explorer. Following is the code. It is working fine in CHROME. Plz help

```
<html>


<head>




<title>Payment Processing</title>
<script language="javascript">
      function exportF() {
  //Format your table with form data



  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").value;
   document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text1").value;

    document.getElementById("input2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text2").value;
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var html = table.outerHTML;


  var url = 'data:application/vnd.C:\\Users\patilch\Desktop\test.xlsx,' + escape(html); // Set your html table into url 
  var link = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
  link.setAttribute("href", url);
  link.setAttribute("download", "export.xls"); // Choose the file name
  link.click(); // Download your excel file  



  var qtApp = new ActiveXObject("QuickTest.Application");
  qtApp.Launch(); // Start QuickTest
  qtApp.Visible = true;




 return false;
}
</script>
</head>


 <body>


<div class="container">

<header>
   <h1>Payment Processing</h1>
</header>


</div>

<content>
<br>
<br>
<br>





</content>



<content>



<form onsubmit="return exportF()">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>File Path</td>
        <td>Sap Generated Path</td>
        <td>Result</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  <input id="text" type="text" /></td>
        <td>  <input id="text1" type="text" /></td>
        <td>  <input id="text2" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="RUN"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>



</form>

</content>
<table id="table" style="display: none">
  <tr>
    <td id="input">
    <td id="input1">
 <td id="input2">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a style="display: none" id="downloadLink"></a>
</body>



</div>



</html>
```

Comment: Please check now

Comment: `QuickTest.Application` ..? What is that? If this is a web-based app, it's strongly recommended not to use ActiveX, since it's often blocked by IE (and always should be). You can't also trust the user has installed Excel ...

Comment: It will Launch QTP, and IE supportrs ActiveX .. Those 3 lines of code var qtApp = new ActiveXObject("QuickTest.Application");
  qtApp.Launch(); // Start QuickTest
  qtApp.Visible = true; 
is working fine .Except downloading Form, everytg is working fine

Comment: I don't see why this is tagged with `uft` and `qtp` tags - the question appears not to be about the tool in any way?